# displaying an image from a directory

Tags: php, sql, image

I need help in displaying my images from the directory images on my public_html directory. It's been uploaded, but it doesn't appear when I run the below php script. Please does anyone know why?

```
<?php
include_once("connect.php");
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php 
 //Retrieves data from MySQL 
 $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM authors") or die(mysql_error()); 
 //Puts it into an array 
 while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
 { 
 Echo "<img src=http://giveaway.comli.com/public_html/images/".$info['photo']."> <br>"; 
 Echo "<b>Name:</b> ".$info['name'] . "<br> "; 
 Echo "<b>Title:</b> ".$info['title'] . " <br>"; 
 Echo "<b>Phone:</b> ".$info['description'] . " <br>"; 
 Echo "<b><a href=".$info['url'] . ">Link</a><br>"; 
 Echo "<b>Country:</b> ".$info['country'] . " <hr>"; 
 }
 ?> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your `public_html` directory really not your site's document root? Perhaps you mean to say:

```
Echo "<img src=http://giveaway.comli.com/images/".$info['photo']."> <br>";
```

Where `/images` is a directory at the site document root.  In a typical hosting situation, `public_html` would be the site document root, meaning that referenced from the web (rather than the file system), it is `/`.

Comment: You're right.. you can look the pictures in that folder.. http://giveaway.comli.com/images/

Comment: @Kelvin then `$info['photo']` is not what you expect it to be. View your page source. I can link directly to `http://giveaway.comli.com/images/LS_The%20Beginning.jpg`, so you need to supply the correct filenames after `/images`

Comment: thank you so much, I think I've seen the error. There's a space, that distorts to img src.

Answer (score 0):

What is the document root of your site? I'm guessing it's `/home/.../public_html`, which means the URL to access the images would really be `http://giveaway.comli.com/images`. Absolute urls of the sort you're using are really only necessary if you're using multiple different hosts/servers for your site, and/or are intending for the html to be portable. You could probably get away with using just `<img src="/images/...">`.

Answer (score 0):

As I can see your document roo directory is `public_html`, so URL path to your photo will be look like this `$image_url = "/images/" . $info['photo'];`